# How to use multiple buttons to populate text box with text string in MS Access Form?

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I am building a form in MS Access and I am trying to use buttons to populate a sequence of text into a text box. The idea is that each button will add onto the information to the string sequence. So far I have only been able to populate the text box with the info of a single button, which gets replaced when another button is clicked.

I used the following for each button:

```
Private Sub btnBP_Click() 
    txtSequence.SetFocus 
    txtSequence.Text = "BP"
```

How can I make subsequent button clicks add onto the information and not replace it?

Answer (score 3):

Don't replace the text, append the new text:

```vb
Private Sub btnBP_Click()

    Me!txtSequence.Value = Me!txtSequence.Value & "BP"

End Sub
```